# Cleaner way to echo multi dimension array

Tags: php, echo

```
echo "{$line['text_1']}";
```

the above echo works fine ,however when it comes to 2d array, in my sublime, only {$line['text_2']} this part work fine. output error both sublime and browser

```
echo "$array_2d[{$line['text_1']}][{$line['text_2']}]";
```

any idea?

---

update

```
echo "$array_2d[$line['text_1']][$line['text_2']]";
```

using xampp, error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs

and I'm just outputting a value from the mysql_fetch_assoc. I can do it in another way by echo '' however I'm trying to make my code easier for future editting and code copy paste

and yes I'm doing things like

```
echo "The price is $array_2d[$line['text_1']][$line['text_2']]"
```

with lots of html code in the double quote.

Comment: am gonna echo muliple line, for html + javascript code. print_r support multiple string?

Comment: `echo "$array_2d[$line['text_1']][$line['text_2']]";` should work, why do you need the {} ?

Comment: not printing whole array, just want the particular result from mysql

Comment: echo "$array_2d[$line['text_1']][$line['text_2']]"; and that will be an error

Comment: Just do     echo $array_2d[$line['text_1']][$line['text_2']];

Comment: To get the best response, please update your question with the purpose of the line and a bit of context (some example code of how it will be used)

Comment: How about `echo $array_2d[%line['text_1]][$line['text_2']];`? or `echo "<pre>"; print_r($array_2d); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: that will output whole array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to say

```
echo "item is {$array_2d[$line['text1']][$line['text2']]}";
```

to get to a subelement.

Of course, this is only really useful when it's not the only thing in the string.  If you're only echoing the one value, you don't need the quotes, and things get simpler.

```
echo $array_2d[$line['text1']][$line['text2']];
```

Comment: oh this is working I can't believe it! My sublime is highlighting this syntax as error approach, web browser able to parse

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to output the array?

if it is for debugging purposes, you can just use the native php functions `print_r()` or `var_dump()`

Answer (score 0):

this should work :

```
echo $array_2d[$line['text_1']][$line['text_2']];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print_r()` to echo the array.

e.g.:

```
print_r($array);
```

Output will be:

`Array ( [test] => 1 [test2] => 2 [multi] => Array ( [multi] => 1 [multi2] => 2 ) )`

Also you can use this to make it more readable in a HTML context:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output will be:

```
Array
(
   [test] => 1
   [test2] => 2
   [multi] => Array
        (
            [multi] => 1
            [multi2] => 2
        )

 )
```

Comment: One of the first things I do on a new project is define `preprint()` to do just this :)

Comment: I always make it smarter, too - to handle arrays, objects, strings, etc, etc - so I can just call the function and not care about what's being printed. Saves typing :)

Answer (score 0):

When echoing variables, you don't have to use the quotes:

```
echo $array_2d[$line['text_1']][$line['text_2']];
```

If you *do* need to output something with that string, the concatentation operator can help you:

```
echo "Array: " . echo $array_2d[$line['text_1']][$line['text_2']];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example variations**

I'm wondering why you would try using the `$line` array as a *key* to access data in `$array_2d`.

Anyway, try this:

```
echo($line['text_1'].'<br>');
```

this:

```
echo($array_2d['text_1']['text_2'].'<br>');
```

and finally this (based on your *"the `$line` array provides the keys for the `$array_2d`"* array example)

```
$key_a = $line['text_1'];
$key_b = $line['text_2'];
echo($array_2d[$key_a][$key_b].'<br>');
```

Which can also be written shorter like this:

```
echo($array_2d[$line['text_1']][$line['text_2']].'<br>');
```

**Verifying/Dumping the array contents**

To verify if your arrays hold the data you expect, do **not** use `print_r`. Do use `var_dump` instead as it will return more information you can use to check on any issues you think you might be having.

Example:

```
echo('<pre>');
var_dump($array_2d);
echo('</pre>');
```

**Differences between `var_dump` and `print_r`**

The `var_dump` function displays structured information of a variable (or expression), including its *type* and *value*. Arrays are explored recursively with values indented to show structure. `var_dump` also shows which array values and object properties are references.

`print_r` on the other hand displays information about a variable in a readable way and array values will be presented in a format that shows keys and elements. But you'll miss out on the details `var_dump` provides.

Example:

```
$array = array('test', 1, array('two', 'more'));
```

output of `print_r`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => 1
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => two
            [1] => more
        )
)
```

output of `var_dump`:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(4) "test"
  [1]=> int(1)
  [2]=> array(2) 
        {
            [0]=> string(3) "two"
            [1]=> string(4) "more"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to echo an array.

The `print_r()` displays information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans whereas the `var_dump()` function displays structured information about variables/expressions including its type and value.

```
$array = 'YOUR ARRAY';
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

or

```
$array = 'YOUR ARRAY';
var_dump($array);
```